# Efficient way of assigning multiple variables in Python

Tags: python

I have code that sort of looks like:

```
def func(a = None, b = None, c= None,..):
   a = a if a is not None else 0
   b = b if b is not None else 0
   c = c if c is not None else 0
   .
   .
   .
   z = z if z is not None else 0
```

Where I am assigning variables from the input. Is there some way of writing it efficiently? That is not just writing it explicitly like above.

Comment: i sincerely hope your function doesn't have 26 explicit parameters

Comment: XD no... but i am giving an example. i have 10 or so, still is tedious to write it. I just want to see if there is a clever way.

Comment: why don't you just use arrays?

Comment: What if you assign variables to 0 instead of None inside the function definition?

Comment: i can do that, and use like `a=b=c=..z=0`, if that is what you are proposing. But I prefer `None` cause that gives flexibility if using mutable objects like `[]`

Comment: Use varargs (*args) or pass a list or tuple. If the parameters have very different semantics, there is no way around dealing with them explicitly, though.

Comment: yeah, that is a good idea. `**kwargs` could be an option.

Comment: Why not just change the default value to `0` instead of `None` and then you don't have to do anything else inside the function...

Answer (score 3):

I'd wonder if you might want to combine your parameters into some collection of sorts and just pass the collection. Even 10 parameters is pushing it IMO. Otherwise,

```
(a, b, c, d, e) = (o if o is not None else 0 for o in (a, b, c, d, e))
```

There is of course the chance you'll type the order wrong on the LHS or RHS.

Comment: ITYM `(a, b, c, d, e) = (o  if o is not None else 0 for o in (a, b, c, d, e))`

Comment: Thanks this also sounds good. Reduces the need for explicitly writing the code.

Answer (score 1):

you can wrap by lambda function

```
def func(a = None, b = None, c= None,..):

    f = lambda x : 0  if x is None else  x
    a = f(a)
    b = f(b)
    #etc ...
```